# I want to change nginx start page(path)

Tags: nginx

my server use meteor, ssl, nginx

when called this url => https://example.com

i want auto change this url => https://example.com/main  <- /main is start page

How can I change it?

don't search find it...

this is my config

```
upstream backend {
  ip_hash;
  least_conn ;
  server localhost:9000;
  server localhost:9002;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/log  main;


  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers 
  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location / {
       proxy_pass http://backend;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}


server {
   server_name example.com;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need simple rewrite rule inside your `location /`

```
 location / {
       rewrite ^/$ /main redirect;
       proxy_pass http://backend;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Do accept the answer by clicking the the green tick near votes